# Paraphrasing and Deleting redundants confusion

Tags: meaning-in-context, expressions, adjectives, conversation, paraphrasing

I came cross the following text in the cambridge online dictionary.

( Used to refer to something that is of higher than usual quality)
I did some paraphrase and deleted what I thought it was redundant.I need someone to tell me whether what I did have been right or not ??

1- Used to refer to something of higher than usual quality.

2- Used to refer to something that is of higher quality than usual.

3- Used to refer to something that is of quality higher than usual.

Comment: Please be assured, there is no useful difference in those three meanings. Some people will say the first should hyphenate "higher-than-usual…" and "quality higher than usual…" might be seen as slightly alien - but the operative word would be "slightly", and in no case would any native speaker misunderstand any of the three. More…

Comment: Further…

Please be clear "came cross…" is simply a mistake, and the text you "came across" wasn't in any "following" text. It was in the "foregoing" or "preceding" text. in the cambridge online dictionary.

The Question title "Paraphrasing and Deleting redundants confusion" is itself greatly confusing. There is no deletion or redundancy and hardly any confusion in the detailed exposition.

If your own explanation refers to "higher than usual quality" why not stick with that?

More…

Comment: Further…

FYI:

"I did some paraphrase…" should be "I did some paraphrasing…" because "paraphrase" would describe what was used, while "paraphrasing" describes how that was done.

"… what I thought it was redundant…" should be "… what I thought (was) redundant…" because "… what… " and "… it…" are fighting to be the subject.

"… what I thought (was) redundant…" works.

"It was redundant…" works. Trying to use both causes contradiction.
 
 and deleted what I thought it was redundant.I need someone to tell me whether what I did have been right or not ??"

Answer (score 1):

To my ear,

3) sounds awkward, and while I don't know if it technically poor grammar, I have never seen it or would never use it.  You could say: "Used to refer to something that is of **a** quality higher than usually seen (in this market)"

2) Is fine, but

1) is best (unless you want to emphasise the idea of seen in this market or this country, etc - in which case use the suggestion in 3) above).

Premium is also a good word (see https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/premium)

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer. But when it comes to number 1 I just removed "that is" from the original text.My question , why whoever wrote this text used "that is " in the first place ??